# Extracting all Colors from Style of Span Class in web page using Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This is my curent code ,im trying to import all the 'background-color rgb  and values from the style in span class.from site below

https://www.asianpaints.com/colour/colour-catalogue.html

[screenshot of page html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00Ijt.jpg)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import os

URL = "https://www.asianpaints.com/colour/colour-catalogue.html"
r = requests.get(URL)

collec = bs(r.content, 'lxml')

color= collec.find_all(class_='color-box3')

print(color)
```

Comment: What does your code currently print, and how is it different from what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RGB values are all done using Javascript which Python or BeautifulSoup will not process which is why you will not see the information you want in the HTML that is returned.

An alternative and easier approach is to spot the request the webpage is making to get the list of colours in the form of a JSON response. The data can then easily be converted to a Python dictionary using the [`json()`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content) requests function and then accessed as a Python dictionary:

```
import requests

URL = "https://www.asianpaints.com/content/ap/en/home/colour/colour-catalogue/jcr:content/oneColumnParsys/colourcatalog.colourfamily.json"
data = requests.get(URL).json()

for shade in data['shades']:
    name = shade['shadeName']
    rgb = f"({shade['shadeR']}, {shade['shadeG']}, {shade['shadeB']})"
    print(f"{name} - {rgb}")
```

Giving you the shades starting as follows:

```
Raven Song - (64, 64, 64)
Platinum Blue - (56, 61, 103)
Black Currant - (65, 64, 67)
Stormy Sky - (58, 65, 80)
Armada - (55, 70, 91)
Navy Blue - (56, 67, 90)
Blue Mountain - (51, 73, 95)
Rich Berry - (77, 67, 72)
```

Tested on Python 3.6.6

Comment: It's a very efficient method to solve the issue @Martin Evans. I've got one question: why can't selenium even load the page mentioned by OP? Provided plus one. Thanks.

Comment: I've not tried selenium on this. Which backend are you using?

Comment: I tried with chrome driver (if this is what you meant by backend). Thanks Martin.

Comment: Use your browser's network tools when loading the page to spot the other urls that are accessed, it is very useful.